# Regex to match two identical consecutive characters

Tags: regex, rust

Let say I have two lines:

1. oaupiimsplsvcsie
2. apjhkutpoiegnxfx

I want to match any character [a-z] that is immediately followed by the same character.

The first line should match because of "ii", but the second line should not match.

Here is my example code that does not work:

```
fn helper_regex(text: &str) -> (bool, Vec<usize>) {
    lazy_static! {
        static ref RE: RegexSet = RegexSet::new(&[
            r"[a-z]{1,}",
        ]).unwrap();
    }
    let matches: Vec<_> = RE.matches(text).into_iter().collect();
}
```

Comment: Since there is no support for backreferences, use `aa|bb|cc..zz`.

Comment: At this time, better to just not use regex.

Comment: Or use [`fancy-regex`](https://crates.io/crates/fancy-regex) which does support back references.

Comment: Oh lord, I tried so many things, but yeah that's why it was not working then. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As per the comments, it can not be done "automatically", it may require a bit more of manual work, so here is a recap of the options:

1. Manually match pairs: `aa|bb|cc|dd|ee|ff|gg|hh|ii|..|zz`
2. Use [`fancy-regex`](https://crates.io/crates/fancy-regex) that supports it (although it may be slow in some cases)
3. Not regex based, but a plain iteration may do:

```rust
fn match_consecutive(s: &str) -> bool {
    let i1 = s.chars();
    let mut i2 = s.chars();
    if i2.next().is_none() {
        return false;
    }
    for (c1, c2) in i1.zip(i2) {
        if c1 == c2 {
            return true;
        }
    }
    false
}

fn main() {
    let should_match = "oaupiimsplsvcsie";
    let should_not_match = "apjhkutpoiegnxfx";
    assert_eq!(match_consecutive(should_match), true);
    assert_eq!(match_consecutive(should_not_match), false);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b78441a1dfa112cc4c2d9385675951c8)

From @SvenMarnach, can be done iterating over the bytes representation too (**ASCII only**):

```rust
fn match_consecutive(s: &str) -> bool {
    s.as_bytes().windows(2).any(|x| x[0] == x[1])
}
```

Or with `itertools::tuple_windows`:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.10.3

fn match_consecutive(s: &str) -> bool {
    s.chars().tuple_windows().any(|(a, b)| a == b)
}
```

Comment: Thanks If i do go with fancy-regex, I will not be able to use RegexSet right?

Comment: @oppsig, I don't think so. But there is no better way to know it than to try! :D

Comment: A more concise implementation for ASCII letter is be `s.as_bytes().windows(2).any(|x| x[0] == x[1])`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, indeed!! I like that!

Comment: @Netwave Consider adding the "ASCII only" statement to that part of the answer so people don't have to find this hint in the comments.

Comment: @peterulb, good point to add.